# Full text search in PostgreSQL JSON (schema-less, NoSQL-like)

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, full-text-search, sphinx, elasticsearch

I trying to decide between PostgreSQL and MongoDB for a project I'll be doing, and I need a schema-less storage and a full text search engine. THe first one is covered by both options, but I'm not so sure about the second one.

Is PostgreSQL able to do full text searches in a JSON data and more specifically, only in certain fields inside that JSON data?

Also, which one is more precise for full text  search, the built-in search engine  in  PostgreSQL or the one in MongoDB?  Or I'll be better using something completely different as Sphinx <strike>or ElasticSearch</strike>? And if the second one, what databases do it support?

Comment: I have the feeling this is too broad. Also, "precise" is probably not a quality of a good text search... ElasticSearch is a database of its own, so to speak, so it doesn't have to 'support' other databases.

Comment: @mnemosyn Ok, I'll edit the ElasticSearch part, but I'm not sure how the  other questions are too broad. Those are really simple questions. 1) Does PostgreSQL support full text search in JSON documents. And 2) With the same data set, which one will get me better results (in a hypothetical search).

Comment: 'better' is at best subjective. Often neither of two (or more options) is truely 'better' - each option just has Pros and Cons, and you have to evualte them all to decide which are the most important considerations for YOUR specific situation,

Comment: @barryhunter I'm completely sure I'm not asking for rocket-science here. If I have "This is a red car" and "What a tall building!" in a DB and I search for "cars", I'd expect the first phrase to show up. I'm sure you can turn this up on another pedantic way, but please, I'm actually asking for the most human-understandable meaning of "good quality results" here, not about any corner case you can think about.

Comment: True you are not asking for science, you are asking for opinion. When nobody has enough information to give a good one.

Answer (score 2):

The full text search capability of PostgreSQL works with the [`tsvector`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSVECTOR) type. Basically:

> Full text searching in PostgreSQL is based on the match operator @@,
>   which returns true if a tsvector (document) matches a tsquery (query)

So given a JSON string, to index certain fields from it, you want to import these fields into a `tsvector`-typed column and link them back to the contents with a foreign key. It may be convenient to make it happen transparently through a trigger, following the model of the built-in `tsvector_update_trigger()`.

From the point of view of the text search engine itself, the origin of the text (JSON field(s) or otherwise) is irrelevant. The document is the `tsvector`.